# How to get the list of all wikipedia categories containing an article?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

From the MediaWiki action API I could get the list of all articles in a category or other subcategories in a category. 
However can you please help me how to obtain a list of all categories which a given article belong to?
It's sufficient to list just the immediate parent Category of an article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Categories](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categories) query module of the API does that. Use something like

```
…?action=query&prop=categories&titles=…
```

Comment: Is there a way to query wikipedia using mediawiki action api locally i.e on localhost? I have setup everything as given in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Running_MediaWiki_on_Debian_or_Ubuntu . But on query I get no pages at all.

Comment: If you can get the wiki itself by visiting index.php on localhost, you also should be able to get the api by visiting api.php. You didn't [disable the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEnableAPI), did you?

Comment: The above query also  returns categories such as "All articles needed additional references" etc., I couldn't see any pattern in those articles to manually remove such categories. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: @router According to the docs, you can omit them by adding `&clshow=!hidden` to your query. Those hidden categories are usually added to articles via templates.